# How to include a hyperlink in a PDF (when creating a PDF) in FME

Tags: fme-form, pdf, hyperlink, fme-transformer

I'd like to create a PDF file with FME, and within this PDF file (which will be used on the computer) I want to create a hyperlink which people can click and that will send them to a website.
So my end product will be a PDF file with a hyperlink which is clickable.

Is this possible within FME?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is quite simple. Just create an attribute called pdf_url with the URL that you want to link to:

[image]

I'm using the 2D PDF writer here and it works well. I'm 90% sure it's not available in the 3D PDF writer though.